# How to get file open and close an event in java

Tags: java, file-io

We can easily track file/folder related events though `java.nio.*` package, but can someone please suggest me, how we can get file `open and close trigger / event` in Java.

For instance, I have `ABC.txt` file in `C:/PQR/` folder and once I double click for opening a file, at that file open event my Java application prints log/SOP. The same happens at the time of closing a file.

FYI, though [`WatchService`](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/file-change-notification-example-with-watch-service-api) we can track file `create / modification / delete` events, but how to catch file open and close event in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the implementation of `FileWatcher` on most JVMs does not let you subscribe to file open / close events, although I can't cite a documentation source for this, as the Java docs leave this undefined as a platform-specific detail.

You can use the "INotify" library on Linux to watch for file open / close events.

(I'm looking for a Java wrapper; the http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/ wrapper library doesn't offer open/close).

See e.g. https://exyr.org/2011/inotify-run/